# Reading the folder inside the project folder with Directory.GetFiles()

Tags: asp.net

My code:

```
 var files = Directory.GetFiles("c:\\a\\b\\projectfolder\\folder1", "*.jpg");
 var files2 = Directory.GetFiles("c:\\a\\b\\projectfolder\\folder2", "*.jpg");
```

I can see folder1 and folder2 folders on Solution Explorer.
I want To avoid problems when the project is moved to another location.what code should i write? of course the code below did not happen.

```
 var files = Directory.GetFiles(folder1, "*.jpg");
 var files2 = Directory.GetFiles(folder2, "*.jpg");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should write this instead of folder1

```
Server.MapPath("/folder1/")
```

The code is as follows

```
var files1= Directory.GetFiles(Server.MapPath("/folder1/"), "*.jpg");
```

same for folder2

```
 var files2 = Directory.GetFiles(Server.MapPath("/folder2/"), "*.jpg");
```

Comment: Nice! Would you consider an explanation to the code? Click to [edit] your answer